# Database design: redundant column vs unused column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

For a project using MySQL, I have a db that looks like this:

**Table #1:** Column A, Column B, Column C, Column D.

**Table #2:** Column A, Column B, Column E, Column F.

As you can see the Columns A and B are redundant through the tables (same type, same kind of information for each table).

Someone suggested me to regroup everything under one table:

**Table #1:** Column A, Column B, Column C, Column D, Column E, Column F.

The problem is that some of my Items use Column C and D and some other use E and F, thus for some rows those columns will always be *NULL*.

What is the recommended practice here? Is there a standard design to follow? What about performance and resources (with thousands rows and ~10 tables)?

One case has **redundant** columns and the other case has **unused** columns.

Or maybe I could split the tables and create a relationship, so it gives something like:

**Table #1:** Column A, Column B.

**Table #2:** Column A (foreign key), Column C, Column D.

**Table #3:** Column A (foreign key), Column E, Column F.

I'm kinda lost here. This is new to me. Thank you for any input.

Comment: there is no standard. there's only what works for you.

Comment: You should use the design that best suit your business requirements. Since we are not of these requirements, it is pretty difficult to recommend a solution for you.

Comment: why can you just have C,D and Type to indicate if it's a CD, or EF type record?  nulls gone, and you're with 4 columns 1 table.  (this assumes a record can't be CD and EF however)

Answer (score 3):

If these are are 1-1 relationships I would stick them into a single table for ease of use. There's no real reason that you can't store NULLS in the table. Personally, I'd rather deal with that than having to deal with keeping keys synchronized between the two tables.

The only major benefit I can see in keeping them separated is that you can put different permissions on the different tables if you want to control what level of information a given user has access to. For example, table A contains the main person record, and table B contains contact information. Sure, your standard user accounts can access that, but you probably don't want every user to have access to table C which contains user SSNs.

If these are 1-n relationships, then you're talking about something different entirely, and it is clearly better to split it into multiple tables.

Comment: I've added an upvote to balance it... I don't see anything wrong with what you're saying.

Comment: @GrahamNicol Don't do that. Vote on the content, not on the votes. If you think the post deserves an upvote, vote accordingly. If you don't think it deserves a downvote, that's not up to you.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I do think it's worth an upvote, I think it's both helpful and explains the logic behind it. That's why I've upvoted it... the fact that it balances out a downvote made with no rationale is merely a happy coincidence.

Comment: Don't assume there's no rationale. If you hover over the downvote, you'll see some of the reasons for voting.  Votes are anonymous for a reason. You can read more about why on Meta.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: We don't have the rep to see the reasoning behind votes.

Comment: When you hover over the downvote/upvote buttons, what do you see?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: *This answer is not useful* / *This answer is useful*.

Comment: That's all there is to it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: interesting, I thought you were talking about something more useful like the review queues. I don't see how this answer is unhelpful related to the question asked, but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your query/write behaviour. If you're measuring on thousands of rows like you say, it won't make a large difference either way.

Perhaps it's better to then plan a schema around what's more intuitive. From that point of view, I prefer seeing redundant data in two tables, to seeing null values all over the place in one table.

Answer (score 0):

The not entirely helpful answer here is "it depends". You should think beyond what columns the tables hold and consider what the tables will be used for.

If you are going to retrieve the data from both Table 1 and Table 2 and present that in a single space, and the where clause will reflect the values of Column A and Column B then having all the data in a single table makes the most sense.

If you are only going to query one table at a time then there's not a lot of benefit in having a single table as you are then "trying to make one thing be two things".

If the number of columns that are "common" between Tables 1 and 2 will grow beyond 2 then splitting the tables and keeping the "domain specific" knowledge in child tables is a great solution (look into "Party" data models for some examples from the CRM world where this is the case).

Most databases will compress empty columns, so there's no physical reason nowadays to choose one over the other.